# SSIS: Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: ssis

I want to iterator the value in xpath /root/filepath in xml_1.xml by using ForEachLoop container in SSIS, see my xml file full path as below:
[image]

my XML file content looks like this:

```
<root>
    <filepath>1.txt</filepath>
    <filepath>2.txt</filepath>
</root>
```

and below screenshots are my packages in SSIS:
[image]

[image]

but when I run this package, I always get following error message:

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\zhanzhex\source\repos\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\loopThrowXml.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC0010014 at Foreach Loop Container, Foreach NodeList Enumerator: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Warning: 0x80019002 at Foreach Loop Container: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Warning: 0x80019002 at loopThrowXml: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\zhanzhex\source\repos\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\loopThrowXml.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[1168] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

can anybody tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: According to this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bb6d476-e2cc-41d0-8165-f17da341912e/foreach-nodelist-enumerator?forum=sqlintegrationservices you should try `//filepath`

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks, but it's not working, I still get same error message